# Print a random string

Tags: c, string, random, ascii

I have a problem generating a random string in a function.

In the code below I have used ASCII characters from 65 to 90. I want to include 48 to 57, skipping 58 to 64.

Is there any way to do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{ 
    char s[30];
    random_string(s, 6,65,90);
    printf("\n%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}

void random_string(char * string, unsigned length,int min,int max)
{
    /* Seed number for rand() */
    srand((unsigned int) time(0) + getpid());

    /* ASCII characters 33 to 126 */
    unsigned int num_chars = length - 1;
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num_chars; ++i)
    {
        string[i] = rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;
    }

    string[num_chars] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that simplest way to achieve that is to reroll `rand()` if you have got number in unwanted range. To specify desired range, you can use bitmask or bool array instead of min/max.

It will look something like this:

```
do { c = rand() % 256; } while (!desired[c]);
string[i] = c;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char* wanted = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

void random_string(char* target, unsigned len, const char* sample, unsigned slen) {
    while(len) {
        *target = sample[rand() % slen];
        ++target, --len;
    }
    *target = '\0';
}

int main() {
    char rnd_str[21];
    //srand(...)
    random_string(rnd_str, 20, wanted, strlen(wanted));
    printf("%s\n", rnd_str);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for that,